# Does Maru OS on Nexus 5 work with Slimport adapter

Tags: maru-os

Question: I would like to know, if Maru OS on the Nexus 5 would work with a slimport Adapter. 
I found one on Amazon:Slimport USB OTG SD TF Card Reader To HDMI  *([https://www.amazon.com/Bonayuanda-Adapter-Slimport-Reader-Google/dp/B016GXVU5S/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1474199607&sr=8-1&keywords=Slimport+USB+OTG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016GXVU5S))*
That would mean I could work over HDMI, charge the device AND work with my USB keyboard and connect an sdcard or usb stick.
I am curious, because I read, that its is not possible to have output and input at the same time on a slimport (*http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2430982)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Maru OS works on the Nexus 5 with SlimPort adapters.

You can charge your device simultaneously while SlimPort is active as long as your adapter supports it (see [the official FAQ](https://github.com/maruos/maruos/wiki/FAQ#can-i-charge-my-device-while-plugged-in-to-a-monitor) for a suggested adapter).

However, it is not possible to simultaneously be in SlimPort/charging mode AND use USB-OTG external storage. SlimPort and USB-OTG can't be active at the same time due to the way SlimPort works. If you're curious why, refer to [this forum post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/maru-os/rsSpHZ0DIJA/mEfp_J9MCwAJ) for more details. In short, the USB data pins are used up by SlimPort when it is active, so you are in either SlimPort mode or USB-OTG mode.

Regarding the particular adapter you linked to, I can't speak about that since I haven't tried it, but it would be wise to ask the manufacturer if this really is SlimPort capable and if it will work on the Nexus 5, so you are sure! If it does work with the Nexus 5, keep in mind that you will only be able to be in SlimPort mode and charge at the same time, you will not be able to use the SD card/USB slots for external storage while SlimPort is active.

Update: You can find a living list of unofficially supported adapters that have been tested by users [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/maru-os/KucsM6gVUL4/pHwJL3XxBQAJ). If you find an adapter that works well and isn't already on the list, let us know on the forum!